# Could not find a declaration file for module implicitly has an 'any' type - while importing part of CommonJS module

Tags: javascript, typescript, commonjs

Currently, the project has a CommonJS module like in order to store the configuration values which are maintained only in one file:

```
module.exports = {
  classA: `classA`,
  classB: `classB`
  classC: `classC`
}
```

This allows later to reuse them for generating JS selectors by doing:

```
const CLASSES = require('./classes')

const SELECTORS = Object.keys(CLASSES).reduce((obj, key) => {
  const selectorKey = key.replace(`class`, `selector`)

  obj[selectorKey] = `.${CLASSES[key]}`

  return obj
}, {})

module.exports = SELECTORS
```

The selectors are later also used in the code logic and are also passed to PostCSS config which generates a list of variables to be used in `.pcss` files.

This is all super handy and helps the developing flow, plus CommonJS allows to import only specific value to the components when needed like:

`import { classA } from './path/classes`

It worked like a dream and it still does, however, importing it the same way in the typescript file doesn't satisfy the tslint constrains and it warns with an error:
`Could not find a declaration file for module implicitly has an 'any' type`:

Here is the **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

So I wonder if there is a valid way to please TS gods and somehow declare the module types, or at least rewrite the presented logic while preserving the current functionality.

P.S: After talking with a duck I came to the conclusion that rewriting it into ts module will prevent the possibility to require the selectors in the postcss config since it doesn't support ES6 `import`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution I've found is to add `"allowJs": true,` option to `tsconfig.js` file

Comment: doesn't do anything for me

Comment: Do you know why the default is "false"?